# Can can we limit the zeros after decimal in an select into statement of stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server

My AvailableBalance column is showing 7 zeros in the output. If I had created a table and given it a numeric datatype, i could've fixed this but just curious if its possible to limit the zeros after decimal to 2 places using "SELECT INTO" statement or not ?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_SMSBRegistration
AS
BEGIN
SELECT
        s.Br, 
        s.Cid, 
        s.MobileNo, 
        s.Acc, 
        s.Status, 
        AvailableBalance = (select dbo.GetAvailBalAmt(acc,0)/100), 
        Cast(b.CurrRunDate As Date) CurrRunDate, 
        Cast(s.ExpiryDate As Date) ExpiryDate,
        sp.SMSBEnabled,
        sp.SMSBRegistrationCharges,
        sp.SMSBRenewalGL

INTO #SMSB_temp
FROM
SMSCIF s
LEFT JOIN
BRPARMS b
ON s.Br = b.Br
CROSS JOIN
SMSParms sp
```

```
0.0000000
0.0000000
14909.7000000
0.0000000
0.0000000
0.0000000
103203.4100000
3826.8700000
0.0000000
131222.6000000
198.9900000
0.0000000
4726.7800000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ROUND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#examples) function in your `select statement` or you can specify the number of decimal points when creating the table.

As an example, by having below definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Dec1] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [Dec2] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [Dec3] [decimal](18, 3) NULL
)
```

if you run below query

```
insert into Table1 (Dec1, Dec2, Dec3)
values (100.0/3.0, 100.0/3.0, 100.0/3.0)
```

You will get below result, which shows different number of decimal points

```
ID  Dec1    Dec2    Dec3
1   33      33.33   33.333
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do with `convert()` or `format()` function.

```
Select convert(decimal(10,0), Yourvalue)
```

10 is the total digits and 0 is digits after decimal

or You can do format as well if you are using SQL server. Both are same but it is mentioned that format is not very performance friendly

```
Select Format(Yourvalue, N'N0')
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add a CAST as part of your select statement like so...

```
DECLARE @myfloat FLOAT
SELECT @myfloat = 2.0/3.0

SELECT @myfloat

SELECT
        Cast(@myfloat As numeric(10,2)) mynum
INTO #SMSB_temp

select * from #SMSB_temp
```